# Custom ListView Items are not clickable

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an application which contains Custom ListView on its main activity. It was working fine but the day before yesterday, list view items are suddenly become non-clickable. I've searched a lot, but no answer solved my this issue. It is strange. Normal list view is working good, but custom isn't. What may be the problem?

**Edit:** Custom List View is as normal as it is, nothing odd. I am giving here `CustomAdapter` class.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
    }
    ClassDetailPedia detailPedia = personDetail.get(position);

    if(detailPedia !=null){
        TextView txtPersonName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPersonName);
        TextView txtReason = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtReason);
        TextView txtTags = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        ImageView imgPerson = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPerson);


        txtPersonName.setText(detailPedia.getTitle());
        txtReason.setText("Description: " + detailPedia.getDescription());
        txtTags.setText("Tags: " + detailPedia.getTags());
        txtDate.setText(GetFormattedDate(detailPedia.getDated()));

        if(detailPedia.getImage() != null) {
            imgPerson.setImageURI(detailPedia.getImage());
            imgPerson.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

and it extends `ArrayAdapter<ClassDetailPedia>`
And here I am setting CustomAdapter

```
ListView lstPersons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDetail);
lstPersons.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list, pediaList));
```

custom_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/shape_list"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_picture"
    android:id="@+id/imgPerson"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Friday, April 1, 2016 @ 8:30pm"
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTags"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Mr. Bill Gates"
        android:id="@+id/txtPersonName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reason: Marketing Strategy"
        android:id="@+id/txtReason"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPersonName"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tags: business, start-up"
        android:id="@+id/txtTags"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtReason"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why use custom ListView and if necessary post source of custom ListView

Comment: I think it was not necessary, but may be it contains problem, so I've edited and posted the source. Using custom list view is the demand of application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made new Application, copied and pasted all the files and code and it's working fine. I don't know what caused the problem and why it is working perfectly know.

Answer (score 2):

Try add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` for the root view of your custom list item (in your case it is `LinearLayout`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/shape_list"
android:gravity="center"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've done this, and it is working. But it doesn't look like it is clicked. Like, it is forced to perform click operation. That effect which android provide on clicking item is not being seen.